# Emotions vs feelings

Tags: meaning, differences

I would really appreciate it if you could explain the difference between the two nouns. Which one has to do with physical sensations and which with mental abilities? It would also really helpful if you could provide an example.

Comment: I do not believe that there is a reliable consensus on the precise meanings and distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in the most general terms, all emotions are feelings, but not all feelings are emotions.

**I'm feeling tired (lucky, lazy, sick, dizzy) tonight.  I've got a suspicious feeling about him. I've got a strange feeling about this presidential candidate.**  These are not emotions.

On the other hand, since emotions (e.g. **love, anger, hatred, worry**) are things you feel, emotions are by nature a type of feeling.

Comment: So could we claim that emotions cause feelings and vice versa?

Comment: I think that it is better to say that emotions are a subset of feelings.  Emotions are a kind of feelings, not the cause of them.  External stimuli cause both, whether a romantic breakup (sadness--emotion) or a heat wave (feeling too hot--not an emotion).

Comment: Can we say,though, that both of them have to do with mental abilities?

Comment: How do you figure?  Even a person of very limited mental ability can feel pain (emotional or non-emotional)--if you pour hot water on him, or if someone he loves dies.  Emotions are actually the opposite of rational thought.

Comment: What I mean is, that if for instance you pour hot water on somebody he/she will feel pain(feeling). But physical pain, that has nothing to do with the mind. If someone he/she loves dies, the pain(emotion) is not physical but mental or psychological. Does this mean that feelings are associated with physical,biological abilities, while emotions with mental ones?

Comment: I think that what you want to know is beyond the expertise of a language specialist; maybe it is better to ask a behavioral psychologist!